# Read properties file in original order from Spring Application Context

Tags: spring, properties

I need to read original order properties file from Spring Application context.

example:

```
A.properties 

1:abc 
2:xyz 
3:qwe
```

The above file I need to get in the same order.

Comment: The example does not look clear to me. Could you please provide at least a snippet of the application context?

Comment: i am loading properties file using spring application context, for ex. i have a properties file empid:123,empname:sowjanya, empaddred:someadd, now i want to get the properties in same order i.e  empid:123,empname:sowjanya, empaddred:someadd, i am using Enumeration<Object> propertyKeys = properties.keys(); this code is not giving the same order that is  empid:123,empname:sowjanya, empaddred:someadd,  but it is giving randomly,  please help me on this.  Thanks! sowjanya